# Running thread for 2 millisecond and then wait for particular time before running it again

Tags: java, multithreading

I have one method execute(data) which  takes considerable time (depending on data like 10 seconds or 20 seconds),  it has timeout feature which is 30 seconds default. I want to test that method. One way of doing it is to collect enough data which lasts more than 30 seconds and then see whether I get timeout exception. Other way of doing it is to use threads. What I intend to do is to run method for some milliseconds and then put thread on wait before I get timeout exception or make it last for some seconds.Can any one please suggest how can I achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

You should walk through the Java Threads Tutorial (Concurrency).  Any answer on Stack Overflow would need to be really long to help you here, and the Threads/Concurrency tutorials already cover this well.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: Ya , i learnt these concepts today before posting question, my doubt is if i use loop for example while(time<requiretime) {execute(data)}, execution will not come back until execute(data) gets completed.

Comment: Have one thread as your controller, which does all of the timing.  Have the work (execute, in this case) done in another thread, which the controller can watch for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
Thread.sleep( millis );
```

to put the thread to sleep for the required time.

Or, you could put your data processing code into a loop, so that it processes it multiple times. This would recreate the scenario of the thread actually processing data for longer than 30 seconds.

Or, you could test your code with a shorter timeout value.

Comment: how will thread putting to sleep help ? One execution of execute(data) method starts, only when method completes, control will come to thread, how can i stop it after running for some milliseconds and restart again

Comment: your question appeared to be "i have a process which runs 10-20 seconds. i have a 30 second timeout. how do i make it run 30+ seconds to test the timeout". Is this not the question? i suggested ways to make the process run 30+ seconds by adding a sleep *to the process*, or shorten the timeout.

Comment: you say you have timeout code to test. or it is just running on one thread and you are asking how to implement the timeout itself?

Comment: ya i have to test the method for timeout. That's only possible if we run method for some milliseconds and then make it wait for time. I dont think if we add sleep before method call or after method call, will be any help.